# Missing vserver-build in set up of guest-system

Tags: linux, debian, x86-64

I am trying to get *vserve*r running on a debian machine. I did install the kernel and tools as dewcribed on the psand.net website.

When I try to set up a guest-server, I get the info, that a generator-file is not found:

```
$ vserver TestServer build -m debootstrap --context 42 --hostname TestServer --interface eth0:192.168.178.3/24 -- -d buster -m http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian
vspace: execvp("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/util-vserver/vserver-build"): No such file or directory
```

The directory contains a lot, but not that one:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/util-vserver/
total 516
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21424 Jan 14  2018 capchroot
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17184 Jan 14  2018 chain-echo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29656 Jan 14  2018 chbind-compat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 37824 Jan 14  2018 chcontext-compat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17184 Jan 14  2018 check-unixfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21352 Jan 14  2018 chroot-sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21440 Jan 14  2018 exec-remount
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17256 Jan 14  2018 exec-ulimit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17200 Jan 14  2018 fakerunlevel
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1003 Jan 14  2018 FEATURES.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17184 Jan 14  2018 filetime
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21424 Jan 14  2018 keep-ctx-alive
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17184 Jan 14  2018 lockfile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13088 Jan 14  2018 mask2prefix
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17184 Jan 14  2018 readlink
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17184 Jan 14  2018 save_ctxinfo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 29776 Jan 14  2018 secure-mount
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17184 Jan 14  2018 sigexec
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5269 Jan 14  2018 start-vservers
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 25568 Jan 14  2018 tunctl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5754 Jan 14  2018 util-vserver-vars
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  2728 Jan 14  2018 vprocunhide
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1630 Jan 14  2018 vservers.grabinfo.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1976 Jan 14  2018 vserver-wrapper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6282 Jan 14  2018 vshelper
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17184 Jan 14  2018 vshelper-sync
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 25536 Jan 14  2018 vsysctl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1620 Jan 14  2018 vsysvwrapper
```

The versions are:

```
Debian 10.8.0 amd64

$ apt-show-versions util-vserver
util-vserver:amd64/buster 0.30.216-pre3131-buster0.1-1 uptodate

$ apt-show-versions linux-image-vserver-4.9-beng
linux-image-vserver-4.9-beng:amd64/buster 4.9.227-2.3.9.12+buster1 uptodate
```

Did I miss something in the installation or do I have to go a different way in setting up the guest-system?

Answer (score 0):

Install package util-vserver-build